Image I/O in RISC-V
I've been tasked with implementing a few image processing functions in RISC-V assembly, using .GRAY images, and wrote a prototype in C to have some sort of guideline, which reads like so
#include <stdio.h>

#define width 400
#define height 599

//read image's pixels
void readGray(unsigned char image[width][height]) {
    FILE *source = fopen("cat_noisy.gray", "rb");

    fread(image, sizeof(unsigned char), width * height, source); /*read through the file*/
    fclose(source);
}
void writeGray(unsigned char image[width][height]) {
    FILE *file = fopen("cat_mean.gray", "wb");

    fwrite(image, sizeof(unsigned char), width * height, file);
    fclose(file);
}

When trying to accomplish the same in RISC-V assembly, I've got this read function
.data
input: .asciz "cat_noisy.gray"
output_mean: .asciz "cat_mean.gray"
output_median: .asciz "cat_median.gray"
error: .asciz "erro a ler ficheiro"
status_read: .asciz "image read"
status_write: .asciz "image written"
image: .space 239600 # (599 * 400)
.text
.global main

readGray: 
    #args
    addi sp, sp, -8 # make space in stack
    sb s0, 0(sp) # store image name byte in stack
    sb s1, 4(sp) # store image size byte in stack
    
    #opening file
    mv s0, a1 # move to where array will be saved
    li a7, 1024 # syscall to open file
    li a1, 0 # syscall to read file
    ecall #open file
    mv s1, a0 # save descriptive in s1
    
    beqz a0, readGray_error # if failed, show error
    
    #if success, read
    li a7, 63 # syscall to read file
    mv a0, s1 # save descriptive in a0
    mv a1, s0 # save image array in a1
    li a2, 239600 # read up to 239600 bytes - image size
    ecall # read file
    
readGray_done: #close file and reset args
    li a7, 57 
    mv a0, s1 
    ecall 
    li a0, 0 
    li a1, 0 
    li a2, 0 
    
    addi sp, sp, 8 
    lb a0, 0(sp)
    lb a1, 4(sp) 
    
#print success
    la a0, status_read 
    li a7, 4 
    ecall 
    ret 
    
readGray_error: #print error 
    la a0, error
    li a7, 4
    ecall 
    j readGray_done

And this write function
writeGray: 
    #args
    addi sp, sp, -8 
    sw s0, 0(sp) 
    sw s1, 4(sp) 
    
    mv s0, a1 
    li a7, 1024 
    li a1, 1 
    ecall 
    mv s1, a0 
    
    beqz a0, writeGray_error 
    
    li a7, 64
    mv a0, s1 
    mv a1, s0
    li a2, 239600
    ecall

    
writeGray_done:
    li a7, 57 
    mv a0, s0
    ecall
    
    li a0, 0 
    li a1, 0 
    li a2, 0 
    
    addi sp, sp, 8 
    lb a0, 0(sp) 
    lb a1, 4(sp) 
    
    la a0, status_write 
    li a7, 4
    ecall 
    ret 
    
writeGray_error: 
    la a0, error 
    li a7, 4 
    ecall 
    j writeGray_done 

And here's my main function
main:
    # readGray
    la a0, input
    la a1, image
    jal readGray 
    
    # writeGray
    la a0, input
    la a1, image 
    jal writeGray
    
    #exit
    li a7, 10 
    ecall 


The issue I've run across is the image either fails to generate, or just generates a black .PNG image (after converting with ImageMagick), even when using my input image - defined in the .data segment - for both read and write (that should make a copy).
Thank you for all the help in advance, apologies for the long post.

This is not a [mcve]. In particular you do not show how you define and pass the image data. Also, what do you mean by "either fails to generate, or just generates a black .PNG image"? How does it fail? Does it sometimes produce a file and sometimes not? Is the file size correct?

@Jester I edited to hopefully have the required context, and as for your question, as of right now, it only generates a black .PNG file (after converting), whereas if I convert the input image, I get the image I'd expect (since I'm reading and writing the input), and yes, i know the size is correct because again, when I convert from .GRAY to .PNG, I get the right aspect ratio on the image

You save and restore $s0 and $s1 wrong in both functions (but should not be the cause of your problem). Check the return value of the read. Also, you are overwriting the input file.

How do I check the return value?

Check that $a0 is the number of bytes and not zero or -1.

It is -1 (0xffffff), how can I resolve this?

According to documentation, the open also returns -1 on error, but you check for zero. So fix that and check that you got the file name correct, you got permissions and you are in the right directory.

The directory is correct, and so is the file name and permissions, but I'll keep on looking into it, thanks!!
